# AmCharts-Sankey Chart Sum of node values

Tags: amcharts5

How can we get the sum of the nodes in AmChart-Sankey.I am using as like below to get sum of nodes but muddle node values getting double.

```
series.nodes.labels.template.setAll({
text: "[bold]{name}[/] (₹{sum})"
-     });
```

If i am using {sumOutgoing} Last node values in sankey are zero.